# How can I efficiently switch on an expression result?

Tags: .net, vb.net, generics, lambda, clr

I'm not sure I'm phrasing that well, but what I want to do is this. I *used* to have code like this:

```
Select Case name
  Case "ThisProperty": ...
  Case "ThatProperty": ...
  ...
End Select
```

but `name` is a property on an object, and I want to do this in a type-safe way, so that if the property changes, I catch it as a compile time error. So I want this kind of pseudo-code

```
Select Case name
  Case PropertyName(Of MyType)(Function(x) x.ThisProperty): ...
  Case PropertyName(Of MyType)(Function(x) x.ThatProperty): ...
  ...
End Select
```

where

```
Function PropertyName(Of T)(propertySpecifier As Expression(Of Func(Of T, Object))) As String
    Return {expression magic to get property name as a string}
End Function
```

My `PropertyName` function works fine, but you can't code a `Select Case` like this, and even if you could, I'm worried that it would be really inefficient, in a tight loop anyway, because of all the expression manipulation. (And the syntax is really tedious, too.)

So I'm wondering if there's a reasonable way to code this to address these two (three) concerns.

Comment: How many values are you dealing with?  Maybe try an enum?

Comment: This will be much easier in [VB.NET 14](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbteam/archive/2014/12/09/new-language-features-in-visual-basic-14.aspx) (VS 2015) because they are adding the `NameOf` operator.

Comment: @JacobRoberts: Then I would just have to update the Enum manually when the property name changes, which would just shift the problem somewhere else. The thing I'm trying to do is have the compiler automatically catch it when I change something.

Comment: @StevenDoggart: Ooh, that's cool! I guess I need to get that version before trying it, but it seems promising.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comment, the `NameOf` operator will be your saving grace in the upcoming VB.NET 14, which will come will Visual Studio 2015.  You won't have to worry about efficiency with it either since it will be evaluated at compile-time rather than using reflection at runtime.

In the meantime, short of creating your own code-generating pre-build action, your best option may be to only evaluate the property names via reflection once, and cache the results.  For instance, you could create a dictionary of actions, like this:

```
Dim actions As New Dictionary(Of String, Action)()
actions.Add(PropertyName(Of MyType)(Function(x) x.ThisProperty),
            Sub() Console.WriteLine("This"))
actions.Add(PropertyName(Of MyType)(Function(x) x.ThatProperty),
            Sub() Console.WriteLine("That"))
```

Then rather than a `Select Case`, you could just pull the desired action out of the dictionary and execute it:

```
actions(name).Invoke()
```

At least then you only have to get the property names once when you build the dictionary.  Finding them in the dictionary after it's built would be very fast.  For a short list, though, you may just want to use a `SortedList` instead of a `Dictionary`.

Answer (score 1):

What Steven Doggart said is right on. Here's an example. I've already used NameOf in a situation where I'm doing name-bound expression evaluation and it replaced all of my literal strings, thus becoming resilient to name refactorings.

(FWIW, VS2015 CTP6 - (the current version as of this writing) - is stable and both VB and C# are feature complete)

```
Sub Main()
    Dim name = "x"

    Select Case name.ToUpperInvariant
        Case NameOf(Grover.x).ToUpperInvariant
            Console.WriteLine("Monkey")
        Case NameOf(Grover.y).ToUpperInvariant
            Console.WriteLine("Giraffe")
        Case NameOf(Grover.Cheese).ToUpperInvariant
            Console.WriteLine("Ferret")
    End Select

    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub

Public Class Grover
    Public x As Integer
    Public y As Integer
    Public Cheese As String
End Class
```

Comment: Ooh, that is lovely. I can see how `NameOf` is going to make things so much better.

Answer (score 0):

Here a routine for exactly this purpose. It is in C#.
But the VB. Net equivalent of static class that accepts an Expression should be possible. Perhaps there is a vb dude that knows how to convert that.

How to treat Strings that refer to POCO properties and get compile time errors when they change.
You use a little lamda expression to refer to the property and you get is name as string back.

```
 public static class MyExtUtilites {
 public static string PropNameAsExpr<TPoco, TProp>(Expression<Func<TPoco, TProp>> prop)      {

        var body = prop.Body as System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression;
        return body == null ? null : body.Member.Name;
    }
  }
```

to use this where the name of property as a string is required.
At compile time the property **propname** must be known in the class MyPoco.

```
  var propNameAsString =  myExtUtilites.PropNameAsExpr((MyPoco p) => myPoco.propname)     ;
```

From a random website that does c# to vb net conversions. Not sure if its Ok.

```
 Imports System
 Imports System.Linq
 Imports System.Linq.Expressions

 Public static Class MyExtUtilites
Public static String PropNameAsExpr<TPoco, TProp>(Expression<Func<TPoco, TProp> prop)      
{

    Dim body As var =  prop.Body as System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression 
    Return body  =  Nothing ? Nothing : body.Member.Name
}
End Class
```

Comment: That's what my `PropertyName` function does and it works fine. My question is about how to use this efficiently (i.e. calling the routine in a tight loop would probably be slow) and how to use it with a Select Case/switch syntax, where this syntax would be awkward or wouldn't even compile

Comment: if you are worried about speed then  a pre phase to build a dictionary may be a good option. Sorry thought you wanted the 'code not quoted'